# Rhapsody: How to add ports and interfaces to a component?

Tags: uml, rhapsody

In Rhapsody, is it possible to draw a diagram like the following?

[image]

I can add ports and interfaces to classes, but Rhapsody doesn't seem to support the port concept for components.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but for Classes. Usage is possible in normal Class or Object Diagrams.

see: 
[IBM Manual "Managing Ports"](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_8.1.1/com.ibm.rhp.uml.diagrams.doc/topics/rhp_c_dm_ports.html)

A "Component" in Rhapsody is different to an UML Component, 
it represents a Executable or Library and therefore there is no special Component Diagram like your Example.